continuity of value function
Let $f:X\times Y\to [0,1]$ be a function such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous in $y$ for all $x\in X$. Define $F(y)=\sup_{x\in X}f(x, y)$. Can we show that $F(\cdot)$ is continuous in $y$ without additional conditions on how $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ behaves with respect to $x$? If no, is there a simple counter example?

It is not. You're asking whether the pointwise supremum of continuous functions is continuous, and to give a counterexample it suffices to exhibit an increasing sequence of continuous functions whose pointwise limit is not continuous; we could take, for example, $f_n(x) = 1 - x^n$ on $[0, 1]$. In a positive direction: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740283/supremum-is-continuous-over-equicontinuous-family-of-functions

Sorry, I am a bit confused. If I define $F(n)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]} 1-x^n$, then $F(n)=1 $ for all $n$.

I meant take the $\sup$ in $n$, so $F(x) = \sup_n (1 - x^n)$, which is equal to $0$ if $x = 1$ and $1$ if $0 \le x < 1$.

ah gotcha! Thank you. Then it seems what we would need here is some form of uniform convergence
