# Axiom of choice and Proofs

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, proof-explanation

I would like an example where the axiom of choice is used to prove something relatively simple. May someone provide an example, please? I’d like to know where the axiom has been used in the proof. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Theorem (AC)** Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

**Proof Sketch 1** Let $X$ be any infinite set and $f$ be a function on $P(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ such that $f(Y)\in Y.$ Then define a sequence $\langle a_n:n\in \omega\rangle$ by recursion: $$ a_{n+1} = f(X\setminus\{a_0,\ldots,a_n\}).$$ Since $X$ is infinite, $X\setminus\{a_0,\ldots,a_n\}$ is never empty, and we can see by construction the $a_n$ are all distinct, so $\{a_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a countably infinite subset of $X.$

**Proof Sketch 2** Let $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha<\beta\rangle$ be a transfinite enumeration of $X.$ Then $\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\omega\}$ is a countably infinity subset of $X.$

The first uses the axiom of choice when we assume that $f$ exists. The second uses the axiom of choice when we assume a transfinite enumeration of $X$ exists.

(Really proof 1 is just the start of the proof from AC that a transfinite enumeration exists, so these are the same proof in spirit.)

The intuition is that we just choose one element, then another, then another, and so on until we have picked out a countably infinite subset. Really, this naive argument is using a weaker form of choice called [dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) and can be easily turned into a rigorous proof from dependent choice.

The theorem is actually significantly weaker than even dependent choice, but that requires less straightforward arguments to see.

Comment: The first proof is really using full choice in the existence of $f$.

Comment: @Logic where is it claimed otherwise?

Comment: You say, "really this argument uses DC..."

Comment: @Logic Read closer...

Comment: (+1), disagreements aside, this is a good answer.

Comment: @Logic Sorry I didn't give a better response to your comments. What I was saying in that paragraph was that the obvious intuitive argument for the proposition (not the semi-formal argument I gave) manifestly uses only dependent choice. I assume I opted not to use dependent choice since I was trying to be clear about the formalities and it wouldn't be as familiar.

Comment: By the way proving **CC** is enough, is not *too hard*, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider $A_{n}$ the set of all subsets in $X$ of cardinality $n$, now using **CC** pick a set from each $A_{n}$ and then consider the union of all the chosen sets, which is countable by “countable union of countable sets is countable”

Comment: In fact the above is the usual argument presented in textbooks.(I think)

Answer (score 5):

I guess the most basic classical example (apart from the usual applications of Zorn's Lemma) is proving that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective map, then there exists $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g$ is the identity on $Y$.

The proof goes: For every $y\in Y,$ *choose* $g(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ (this set is non-empty by surjectivity). Now, by definition $f(g(y))=y$. Without the axiom of choice you cannot *simultaneously* choose the $g(y)$'s to construct a well-defined map.

Comment: So could I rephrase AOC by saying that for any non empty set we can find an element within the set?

Comment: @topologicalmagician: No, that would not be equivalent. But an equivalent formulation is: For every set of disjoint nonempty sets, you can find a set that contains exactly one element from each member set.

Comment: @topologicalmagician No, that would be obvious. You need it specifically to prove that given a family $\mathcal F$ of non-empty sets there is a subset $f\subseteq \mathcal F\times \bigcup\mathcal F$ such that the following two conditions hold: 1) for all $x\in \mathcal F$ there is some $y\in x$ such that $(x,y)\in f$; 2) for all $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\in f$ either $x_1\ne x_2$ or $y_1=y_2$. I.e. that there is a function assigning to each set of $\mathcal F$ one of its elements.

Comment: @celtschk in the example provided, the collection of disjoint sets is the set containing only X, Y, right?

Comment: No, the collection of disjoint sets is $\{f^{-1}(\{y\})|y\in Y\}$. You need to pick one $x$ from each of these sets and name it $g(y)$.

Comment: @topologicalmagician: See above comment by WoolierThanYou. (I post this comment because Woolier forgot the at-attribution, so you might not get notified.)

Comment: @celtschk is there an axiom which doesn’t require the sets to be disjoint?

Comment: @topologicalmagician: You may as well pretend they are for the purpose of making the selection. But yes, in general you just have a collection of sets that are non-empty, and you need to pick an element from each one. For instance you could have some number of copies of the same set, and you could pick the same element every time - that is a valid choice function.

Comment: @topologicalmagician: Even with the axiom of choice, it may not be possible to get a set with exactly one element from each subset; consider e.g. the set $\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}$. However you can circumvent this by marking the elements with the set they came from, that is forming pairs where one element is the originating set, and the other one is the chosen element. But this set of pairs is nothing but the choice function.

Comment: @celtsch so I would be correct in rephrasing AOC by saying that given a collection A of non empty sets there exists a set C that contains exactly one element from each element in A. Right?

Comment: @topologicalmagician: No, that's what I gave a counterexample of. With $A=\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}$, there is no such set $C$. Say the set $C$ contains $a$. Then it cannot contain $b$ (two elements from $\{a,b\}$, nor $c$ (two elements from $\{a,c\}$. But then it contains no element from $\{a,c\}$. However if you “tag“ the elements, that is, replace the $a$ from $\{a,b\}$ with the pair $(\{a,b\},a)$ and so on, then the sets *are* disjoint and you can generate a set $C$ consisting of such pairs, e.g. $C=\{(\{a,b\},a),(\{a,c\},a),(\{b,c\},c)\}$. But this is simply a choice function on $A$.

Comment: @celtschk beautiful. I see it. So given any non empty indexed family of non empty sets I can always choose elements from each set in the indexed family.

Comment: @topologicalmagician: I don't know what you mean by “indexed family”, therefore I can neither confirm nor contradict that claim.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, and you have $a\in A, b\in B$, then their cartesian product $A\times B$ obviously contains the tuple $(a,b)$, hence is non empty.
Surprisingly, such a statement for products with infinitely many factors needs the axiom of choice.

> **Statement.** The cartesian product of arbitrarily many non-empty sets is non-empty.

*Proof.* (Sketch)

To show that the product is non-empty, we have to find an element in it. But if $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets, then any tuple in $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ has to contain one element from each of the $X_i$. Hence, we need the existence of such a choice which is provided by the axiom of choice.

$\square$

And the axiom of choice is actually equivalent to that statement.

Comment: (+1) This is perhaps the simplest application of choice!

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice, each implies the other, so AC implying $p$ might suit your purpose. The example I'll pick is [any set $X$ is well-orderable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem).

Let $f$ denote a choice function on the non-empty subsets of $X$. For any ordinal $\alpha$, define $\iota(\alpha):=f(X\setminus\{\iota(\beta)|\beta\in\alpha\})$, so $\iota(\emptyset)=f(X),\,\iota(\{\emptyset\})=f(X\setminus\{\iota(0)\})$ etc. We thus inject ordinals into $X$ until the values $\iota$ has assumed comprise all of $X$. This must happen eventually, because ordinals don't form a set and, by replacement, can't be injected into one. But if $\alpha$ is the least ordinal for which $\iota(\alpha)$ is undefined because we'd be trying to compute $f(\emptyset)$, the codomain of $\iota$ is just $\alpha$. Because we've bijected $X$ with $\alpha$, we've also well-ordered it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of standard theorems which invoke some variant of the *Axiom of Choice* (AC). For example, the *Baire Category Theorem* requires what is known as the *Axiom of Dependent Choice* (the strongest form of AC accepted by constructive mathematics). For the full Axiom of Choice implying a mathematical proposition there is  *Tychonoff's Theorem* (wikipedia actually has a really cool proof of this theorem implying AC) **or**:

> **Statement.** Let $\{f_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}$ be an equicontinuous and uniformly bounded family of real-valued functions defined on a metric space $M$. Then $f(x):=\sup_{\alpha \in A} \{f_\alpha (x) \}$ is continuous on $M$.

[See my post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961452/continuity-of-max-f-1x-f-2x-cdots-f-mx-at-a/961604#961604)

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim.** Suppose that $\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of sets such that $|A_n|=2$ for all $n$, then $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is countable.

*Proof.* For each $n$, choose $a_n\in A_n$, and let $b_n$ be such that $A_n=\{a_n,b_n\}$. Now take the map $2n\mapsto a_n$ and $2n+1\mapsto b_n$. This is a surjection from $\Bbb N$ onto $A$, and therefore $A$ is countable. $\square$

The proof can be extended for $A_n$ to be any other size of countable set (finite or infinite), but the above is the simplest case. And indeed, it is also necessary, since it is consistent that the axiom of choice fails and there is such a family whose union is not countable.